Why can a classifier's predicted labels be improved (with respect to the same metric the classifier optimizes) by adjusting classification threshold?
I am hoping to enhance my (and others' perhaps too) understanding of some basic principles, which seem surprisingly elusive.
For a start, I would like to consider imbalanced binary classification, where the cost of a false positive is the same as of a false negative. A classifier trained to optimise a specific metric (for example, the Matthews Correlation Coefficient, but any should do) provides a 0-1 score reflecting the (likely uncalibrated) probability that a given instance (data point) belongs to the positive class, which translates into a positive predicted class label if that score is above the classification threshold, and negative predicted label otherwise. The classification threshold equals 0.5 by default, but it seems common practice to adjust the threshold to improve the classification performance ('performance' still meaning the metric originally optimised by the algorithm), without altering the model, nor its predicted scores, changing only the threshold and the predicted labels.
This seems puzzling to me, because I would expect most models to do this internally, by adjusting the scores so that they are optimal for a given threshold (say, 0.5). I would expect there to be some relatively straighforward way of transforming the scores while keeping the threshold constant, so that the predicted labels would be the same as the labels resulting from shifting the threshold (while keeping scores constant). By "relatively straighforward" I mean such that most classifier models can implement it. If the scores could take any positive or negative value, then shifting the threshold by a value would be equivalent to (i.e., yield the same predicted labels as) shifting scores by the same value in the opposite direction (which is trivial for any model). I'm guessing there is an issue stemming from the fact that the scores are bound between 0 and 1; but then again, aren't there classifiers based on unbound scores and decision functions where positive label is produced for a positive score, and negative otherwise? Do they benefit from threshold optimisation?
In my view, a model mathematically capable of adjusting scores equivalently to shifting threshold should not benefit from threshold optimisation.
So the question is why do people do it (or when). Why can e.g. MCC be raised further by adjusting a threshold for predictions obtained from a classifier already trained to maximise MCC?
Possible explanations that spring to mind but ring untrue:

no popular classifier, incl. neural networks and ensembles, is capable of transforming predicted scores in a way that is equivalent to shifting the threshold;
scores can be transformed, but associated noise of the scores is also transformed, in a detrimental way;
models that are seemingly trained optimising a certain metric, actually aren't (an approximation is used, or a loss function based on scores rather than labels);
the improvement in performance (after adjusting threshold) can only be observed on validation or test but not train set, meaning that it is a form of fine-tuning on validation, not of hyperparameters, but of actual basic parameters of the model, just all at once;
...

I just hope for some insightful discussion here, or maybe someone pointing out a flaw or implicit assumption in my reasoning. Or a resource to check. Thanks!

I'm not sure how many classifiers directly optimize a hard-class prediction metric anyway.

This seems puzzling to me, because I would expect most models to do this internally, by adjusting the scores so that they are optimal for a given threshold (say, 0.5). The model does not know about any kind of threshold, does it?

" but it seems common practice to adjust the threshold to improve the classification performance" just because something is common practice, doesn't mean that it is good practice.  "where the cost of a false positive is the same as of a false negative." if that is true, it is very likely that it would making a serious mistake to adjust the threshold, mostly likely reflecting a lack of understanding of cost-sensitive learning.

Even if in your example a classifier is already trained to maximize MCC, since MCC is not a proper scoring rule, it cannot correctly account for the prediction uncertainty of its trained model which could still be improved further by various calibration methods such as Platt scaling applied to validation set ideally. For DNN classifiers Guo et al showed empirically that a simple temperature scaling as a single parameter variant of Platt scaling produces the lowest expected calibration error (ECE) on a variety of DNN classification problems in their 2017 paper On Calibration of Modern Neural Networks.

Modern neural networks exhibit a strange phenomenon: probabilistic error and miscalibration worsen even as classification error is reduced...  Nevertheless, simple techniques can effectively remedy the miscalibration phenomenon in neural networks. Temperature scaling is the simplest, fastest, and most straightforward of the methods, and surprisingly is often the most effective.

In summary calibrations usually do not affect the identity of the most probable class label, so these methods may have little impact on classification accuracy. However, they do improve calibration performance in terms of forecasting, for example, the effect of relatively high temperature (>1) in temperature scaling is to make the trained model's predictive distribution less peaky.
